# DvdFab does not start after last update

Tags: 11.10, wine

Since last update of DvdFab, I am unable to open the software.

It seems to work fine on the first screen, in which I choose the option to use. Once I click on it, the program does not load up and the "Wine" icon in Unity disappears, getting a blank desktop.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, last updated two days ago and the DvdFab version I've got is 8.1.3.2.

Has anybody had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried different settings on "Configure Wine".

DVDFab works up to Windows version 2003.

The problem has been solved.